# How can I programmatically position multiple backgrounds using Sass/Compass?

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to figure out how to position multiple backgrounds programmatically in Sass, using a single image (sprite) and multiple positions.

The amount of backgrounds depend on the number assigned to $columns. I am running the number of columns through a function to determine the left offset. The top position references the location of the next sprite image.

desired css:

```
.col-numbers {
background:
  url('numbers.png') 0 0 no-repeat,
  url('numbers.png') 94px -18px no-repeat,
  url('numbers.png') 188px -36px no-repeat,
  url('numbers.png') 282px -54px no-repeat,
  url('numbers.png') 376px -72px no-repeat;
}
```

I've tried a simple loop, which of course doesn't work because it just repeats the background property, and doesn't produce the desired effect..

```
$columns: 12;

.col-numbers {
  @for $n from 1 through $columns {
    $left: (columns($n - 1, $columns) + gutters($columns));
    $top: (-$n + 1) * 18px;
    $background-pos: '#{$left} #{$top}';
    background: image-url('numbers.png') #{$background-pos} no-repeat;
  }
}
```

I'm thinking I might have to create a function that returns a list of values that can be passed back, but am at a loss on how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Thanks to hopper's answer, I was able to achieve the desired result by a slight modification (due to an error on my part in the original posting).

```
  $output: ();

    @for $n from 1 through $columns {
      $left: (columns($n - 1, $columns) + gutters($columns));
      $top: (-$n + 1) * 18px;
      $output: join(
        $output,
        (image-url('numbers.png') #{$left} #{$top} no-repeat),
        comma
      );
    }

    background: $output;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SASS [join function](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#join-instance_method) to join two lists together, and then use that master list as the background value. For example:

```
$columns: 12;

.col-numbers {
  $output: ();

  @for $n from 1 through $columns {
    $left: (columns($n - 1, $columns) + gutters($columns));
    $top: (-$n + 1) * 18px;
    $output: join(
      $output,
      (image-url('numbers.png'), $left $top no-repeat),
      comma
    );
  }

  background: $output;
}
```

For more information, check out the [lists](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#lists) section of the [SASS reference](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html).

Comment: I had a comma in there where I shouldn't have, by interpolating $left and $top,  and removing the comma after the image, I was able to get the desired effect. Thanks, I've learned a lot.

Comment: Just for clarification, what is the $output: (); intended to do.. declare the variable used outside of scope and identify it as a list? ()

Comment: That's exactly right! The "()" denotes an empty list in SASS, so that on the first pass through the loop join() will merge the background with the empty list. Otherwise, SASS will complain about $output being uninitialized.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation & code example hopper, it really helped me understand what's going on here. Hopefully it helps out others as well. I was able to implement responsive numbers on top of Compass grid-background with support up to 61 cols using a 2KB png sprite. Great for debugging. https://skitch.com/krisbulman/ej55h/mozilla-firefox

Comment: Seems there is a bug somewhere along the way with compass compile when using this method, I've created a sample project & an issue in the Compass issue queue: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/989 (just for tracking if anyone else is reading this topic).